# Best practices for copying container images between ECRs in different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-image, amazon-ecr

I wonder what are best practices for copying Docker container images from ECR to ECR in AWS.

I have to copy container images periodically between multiple ECR repositories, each placed in separate AWS account - like mirroring but with specific filters for what to copy and what to skip. I wrote a script that does this work by pulling missed images from the 'source' ECR to an EC2 VM, and pushes them to the 'target' ECR.
This works, but I am not satisfied by the performance of doing that in a single thread, and it's not network throughput limiting it but 'expences' to wrap commands, run some necessary calls to AWS, etc.

So I am thinking of rewriting the script to a multi-thread application, but I wonder if I'm inventing a bicycle, and there is some known and better solution for this task.

Comment: Haven't tried it by myself, but seems legit, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/replication.html

Comment: Thank you Sándor, I'll try to experiment with this.

Comment: Sándor, I've found that this approach does not fit my specific use case (it is not always good that all images to be replicated everywhere before they've been tested intensively at one of environments), but it could work for someone else of course. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As it was confirmed by AWS support, there was no 'out-of-the-box' way to do this job, other than direct mirroring of entire repository.

Thus I rewrote the tool for doing it in a smarter and faster way, and published it.

https://github.com/dfad1ripe/aws-ecr-cross-account-clone

To use it, both source and destination AWS accounts should be defined as profiles in ~/.aws/credentials, and the host should be running either Docker Engine or Docker Desktop.